# How do I require a private ruby gem from another private ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, gemspecs

I have a private gem, called `X`, whose source code is hosted on Github. If I want to use `X` in a project, I add `gem 'X', :git => 'git@github.com:my-org/x.git'` to my project's `Gemfile`. I can then launch `irb` and type `require 'bundler/setup'` and then `require 'x'`. The functionality of `X` is available.

Now, I have a different private gem, called `Y`, whose source code is also hosted on Github. I want to use `X` from within `Y`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

If your ssh key is configured on github this will work:

```
gem 'gem', :git => 'git@github.com:user/gem.git', :ref => 'ref'
```

You can test it by running `ssh -t git@github.com`

Other options are using your username and password and basic auth:

```
gem 'gem', git: 'https://user:password@github.com/user/gem.git'
```

Or more safely using environment variables to protect your password:

```
gem 'gem', :git => "https://#{ENV['gem_username']}:#{ENV['gem_password']}@github.com/gem.git"
```

This last example is also a good idea if you're using a CI server to deploy your project.

Comment: Assuming you are suggesting these lines go in the gem's `Gemfile`, this does not work. When running `gem build y.gemspec` you will recieve an error that states: `The git source git@github.com:my-org/x.git is not yet checked out. Please run \`bundle install\` before trying to start your application`.

Comment: Yes, you need to run `bundle install` before building